# Prevent browser to autocomplete https/https

Tags: http, browser, https, autocomplete, protocols

Anyone knows how to prevent browser auto complete for http/https. If i did access a site on https , and now i want to access it on http, the browser dosent let me, it automatically puts https in front of the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the auto complete that sends you to https.  I did some tests using wireshark connecting to http://www.google.com.  See the results.  The host is redirecting to the HTTPS site.

[image]